# Does a Monk have any reason to take the Mobile feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, monk

I am currently playing the *Curse of Strahd* adventure and we just leveled to 8. I was thinking about taking the Blade Mastery feat (from [Unearthed Arcana: Feats](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/dnd/ua-feats-v1.pdf)) or the [Healer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/healer) feat (PHB, p. 167). A fellow player suggested I take the [Mobile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/mobile) feat (PHB, p. 168) for my monk.

**Is there any reason to choose the Mobile feat over another possible feat (such as Blade Mastery, Savage Attacker, Durable, Healer) for a monk since they already get increased movement?**

My stats are:

- Str 10
- Dex 19
- Con 16
- Int 12
- Wis 18
- Cha 10

I am a half-elf of the high elf variant with the *fire bolt* cantrip. I have no other feats currently.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We need to know what game your playing in order to answer this question. This website handles a wide variety of RPGs. Looks like we had enough information to figure it out this time, but in the future you should include it in the tags. Happy stacking!

Comment: this was my first ever question on here and I am still unsure as to how to ask the questions. V2Blast did a good job with rewording the question although I don't know how he put the links into the question. I did intend it to be about d&d 5e.

Comment: Can you give more details on your character, i.e. attribute scores, feats you might have already taken, race, etc.?

Comment: my stats are str 10 dex 19 con 16 int 12 wis 18 cha 10. I am a half elf high elf variant with the cantrip fire bolt. I have no other feats currently.

Comment: You can find editing help (e.g. for formatting) here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### There are multiple benefits

Mobile feat does not only increase your movement speed. It also negates difficult terrain when you Dash and allows for the avoidance of opportunity attacks.

> When you make a melee attack against a creature, you don't provoke opportunity attacks from that creature for the rest of the turn, whether you hit or not.

This is a very powerful feature for a monk especially since they can get many attacks to hit all of the enemies in melee using Flurry of Blows.

And, 10 extra movement speed doesn't hurt. There is almost never a case where you have too much movement speed as repositioning in combat (especially if you are avoiding hazards or threat areas of enemies) can take a lot of movement.

Comment: I see your point for this feat but I want to know is it a better choice than the other feats I mentioned or possibly another feat.

Comment: @Eternallord66 whether it is better or not will depend on a lot of factors and what you mean by better.

Comment: more beneficial in the context of fighting strahd in his castle would be a good example. I have a magic +1 sword that I can use to cast crusaders mantle. we are set to fight him on his balcony. in my party we have a dpr sorcerer, aoe/healing sorcerer, paladin, rogue thief and myself the open hand monk.

Comment: These should be included in the question itself, or maybe another question altogether so it doesn't invalidate David's answer. Either way, they shouldn't be left as comments in his answer.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I am still learning this site.

Answer (score 5):

As [David mentions in his answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134653/43856), possibly the greatest bonus from Mobile is actually the bullet

> When you make a melee attack against a creature, you don't provoke opportunity attacks from that creature for the rest of the turn, whether you hit or not.

However, you seem focused on the fight against Strahd, and from my experience, Opportunity Attacks from Strahd aren't exactly what you should be worried the most here. From your stats, you have 19 dex and no other odd score, and also you are a half-elf. Monks get a lot from bonus Dex - higher chance to hit, higher damage, higher AC, higher everything. This highly indicates to me that a feat with half-ASI, i.e. +1 Dex, would improve your character by a lot more than taking either a Full-ASI (+1 Dex +1 another thing) or a feat without any ASI.

I don't intend to include much math here since this is not exactly an optimization question, but Elven Accuracy from Xanathar's Guide to Everything, if you have some way to consistently get advantage, brings a decent advantage over +2 ASI (check this question for example [What is better early game, dex increase to 18 or elven accuracy for fighter-rogue?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128515/43856)). In your case, you don't actually have to trade the +2 ASI because you are already at an odd stat, so you actually get both the bonus.

As another option, if your party chooses to face Strahd only at 12th level, which is possible IIRC, you might be interested in getting +1 Dex, +1 Wisdom now, and at level 12 getting Resilient (Wisdom), giving you proficiency in Wisdom saving throws, which are helpful against his charms and some spells (such as Polymorph), and the missing +1 Wisdom, putting you at full 20 Wisdom, increasing your AC again and some damages.

Comment: I never thought of Elven Accuracy. that could be very good for me. however, I should mention that I forgot to mention that I have a curse on me that gives me my CON ability score (16) as HP during short rests while also making me weak against piercing, slashing and bludgeoning damage. In addition we are on a timeframe and the DM says we may be facing Strahd at level 8 or 9 due to him moving in a couple of weeks.

Comment: @Eternallord66 yeap, 9 or 10 is the usual. But I think you *can* delay it to 12, IIRC. 8 might be too soon but should be beatable with smart play from the party and not the smartest play from Strahd.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the Monk to take the Mobile feat is not the extra movement, but rather to not provoke opportunity attacks from any creature that you have attacked, hit or not. This is extremely useful as you can move about, attack a large number of targets, and then escape without even been attacked!